# Getting error in sendmail nameserver not found

Tags: linux, sendmail, nameserver

I added this code to sendmail.mc file:

```
dnl # Uncomment and edit the following line if your outgoing mail needs to
dnl # be sent out through an external mail server:
dnl #
define(`SMART_HOST',`in.hes.trendmicro.eu')dnl
dnl #
```

I did the m4 conversion to make the sendmail.cf file, there is the following code added:

```
DSin.hes.trendmicro.eu
```

I get the following error in the /var/mail/example:

```
<example1@example.com>... Host unknown (Name server:example.com: host not found)
```

I don't know what I did wrong here, new to sendmail.
Thanks for helping !

Comment: Even with smart host sendmail by default does a lot DNS checks e.g. it checks in DNS every domain in every address in To:, Cc:, From: headers.

Comment: Now the connection just times out, but pinging and dig works. 

Deferred: Connection timed out with in.hes.trendmicro.eu.

Comment: Do you get SMTP greeting message when you telnet smtp(25) port on the smart host? [Translated: Is it sendmail fault?]

Comment: No, it just says trying with the ip number. Is it possible the port is blocked on their side or on my end? Error message: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host.

Comment: Use a tool like `tcptracerote` to debug connectivity issue.

Comment: So when i use tcptraceroute without a specified port i can reach it. When i specify port 25 the destination can't be reached.

Answer (score 1):

> Name server:example.com: host not found

Is not necessarily a sendmail specific problem but most likely a generic DNS issue. The hostname (or MX record) for example.com can't be resolved.

Check if `dig any example.com` also gives an error => DNS problem that needs to be resolved as even when configured with a Smart Host by default sendmail still does a DNS lookup.

Comment: I got a positive answer back : 

Well the dig command gives this output, which is positive:

arne.banck$ dig in.hes.trendmicro.eu

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> in.hes.trendmicro.eu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47394
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;in.hes.trendmicro.eu.  IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
in.hes.trendmicro.eu. 1556 IN A 150.70.226.152

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.12.3#53(192.168.12.3)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 26 08:50:10 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54